# Is there an IPC transport for MassTransit?

Tags: masstransit

It's my understanding that the MassTransit in-memory transport only supports endpoints within the same process.  Assuming that's accurate, is there an IPC transport available?  If not, is there any documentation on how to go about implementing a custom transport?

Comment: Is this a programming related question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no interprocess communication transports for MassTransit, the transport all use a message broker (such as RabbitMQ, ActiveMQ, etc.).

There isn't specific guidance on how to create your own transport, the only suggestion is to use an existing transport (such as the in-memory one) to build a new transport for IPC (if that's what you want).